# I'm getting erros when running my JAVA webdriver code. It's to do with the ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try and run the following code I get errors to do with `ChromeDriver`.

I'm new to this but **I can see that the code gets as far as row 11 but then it fails**.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Matts Learning\ChromeDriver\ChromeDriver
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>       at TestTiscaliLogin.main(TestTiscaliLogin.java:13)

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: If you are still facing error, can you please show the code that leading to the above mentioned error?

Comment: I'll close this one off. All works fine now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download latest version of Chrome Driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) -> Under Downloads.

Download the zip file and extract the contents. The contents will have the exe which you need to use. You can also set it by using -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:://you_path_for_exe//chromedriver.exe");
```